# How to get the chart's resolution while using MTF

Tags: pine-script

With the support of [multi-timeframe (MTF) functionality](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000584445-how-to-use-multi-timeframe-mtf-functionality/):

> the value of timeframe.* variables will represent the resolution the script is currently running on as determined by the value of the Timeframe field in the script's Inputs, regardless of the chart's resolution.

So how to get the chart's resolution now that it's different from the script resolution? Or how to know whether they are different?

Answer (score 0):

`timeframe.period` returns your chart's resolution.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

in_htf = input.timeframe("", "Timeframe")

curr_tf = timeframe.period

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    s = (in_htf == curr_tf) or (in_htf == "") ? "True" : "False"
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = s)
```

[image]

Comment: You're not using the default MFT functionality, with that `timeframe.period` is determined by the user input.